# Languages ; keyboard set up etc

Tags: keyboard, language-support

I have a new [refurbed] Lenovo Yoga. It’s sold as UK and has a physical UK keyboard. It was shipped from Germany.
The BIOS is written in English. I can see no language options in the BIOS.
When I install Ubuntu, all goes well, the local / region I’ve set to UK, English. The “test keyboard” during install, all types in English. No issues.
After re-boot Ubuntu is all in English. However, it will only type in German. The character set is German.
However all the regional settings, language settings etc, are still UK English.
I’ve installed / reinstalled 1804 and 2204 with no luck. I’ll try 16xx next.
Assuming this is the same, does anyone have any other clues ?
Thanks.

Comment: Does it do this in other distro's too? Fedora for example? It's a really weird issue.

Comment: Hi @Kevin ..... I'm not sure. I'm trying Ubuntu 1604 now to see what happens and then I'll move to Fedora, or other. I have UbuntuUnity on another machine and am hoping for the same on my new refurbed !

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the output from these two terminal commands: 1. `cat /etc/default/keyboard` 2. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

Comment: Hi @GunnarHjalmarsson ..... the problem I have is typing ! The keyboard mapping is all over the place. I'm trying some other things right now but will get the Terminal outputs when I can. Thanks P.

Comment: You should be able to copy and paste those commands.

Comment: My own update : I’ve tried different flavours of Ubuntu and different versions of different flavours, going back to 1604. All have the same “mapping” issue. 

I have also rolled Fedora on the same machine and have the same issue there as well, maybe even worse, as it more visible during the install [maybe because of the different way Fedora installs compared to Ubuntu]. Either way, this is not a distro’ issue.

My view is that this is way down in the BIOS somewhere and I need to try and work that out. Or I return the machine which was a refurbed machine.

Comment: If you don't answer follow-up questions requesting additional info, why are you at Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: 1 : I did answer; typing is the issue so copy paste does not work either. I'm not able to open terminal, nor this www site, nor sign in. Was that not clear.
2 : I'[ve done an update to partially answer the issue but also what I am doing to work it out. It's an update.